# Setting WPF ProgressBar Maximum from Task

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Updating .NET ProgressBar `Value` from a Task is easy by using an instance of Progress:

```
IProgress<int> progress = new Progress<int>(_ => progressBar.Value = _);
int result = await Task.Run(() => Method(progress));
```

followed by calling `Report` from the Task's Method:

```
 private int Method(IProgress<int> progress) 
 {
    ...
    progress.Report(n);
    ...
 }
```

But how do I set ProgressBar `Maximum` from a Task?

Comment: Do you want to set the maximun value to the progress bar, but you don't know which is the maximun value inside the method?

Comment: @julianzapata The `Maximum` will become known only after Task's Method starts executing.  I don't know what it will be before running the Task.

Comment: Oks, I don't know exactly what you are trying to do but you can make a conversion to one hundred and assume that this is your maximun value and make the calculation inside the method to report the progress. Inside the method the calculation will be **max** * 100/**progress** where **max** is the maximun value know inside the method and pass the result to  progress.Report(result).

Comment: @julianzapata I found a solution already.  Posting soon.

Comment: @julianzapata What are you doing? Converting progress to percentage would eliminate his problem of not knowing the maximum progress value in advance of the progress start. In case of percentage, the `ProgressBar.Maximum` would always be '100'. The formula is: _progressValue_ * _100_ / _maxValue_ = _percentageValue_. But since the default value of `ProgressBar.Maximum` is '1', the easiest would be to use simple decimal representation:  _progressValue_ / _maxValue_ = _decimalValue_.

Comment: Yes @BionicCode, I did a mistake in the calculation. Your formula is the correct. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

The solution was obvious but missed me due to the late hour:

```
public class ProgressData
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public int Maximum { get; set; }

}
```

```
public void ReportProgress(ProgressData progressData) 
{
   progressBar.Value = progressData.Value;
   progressBar.Maximum = progressData.Maximum
}
```

```
IProgress<ProgressData> progress = new Progress<ProgressData>(ReportProgress);
int result = await Task.Run(() => Method(progress));
```

and

```
private int Method(IProgress<ProgressData> progress) {
    ...
    progress.Report(new ProgressData { Value = 1, Maximum = 10 });
    ...
}
```

From https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19020.progress-of-a-task-in-c.aspx

Comment: Minor recommendation: use `struct` instead of `class`. Value types avoid lots of small instances requiring GC, and enforces the "copy, don't reuse" requirement of `IProgress<T>.Report`. Also, I recommend `progress?.Report(...)` so that `progress` can be `null`.